# Dialogflow update context in the console

Tags: session, dialogflow-es, context-switch, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a requirment where I want to append the parameter to context in the frontend screen.
I can do it via webhook as :

```
1. Get Context Param1 and Parameters Param1
2. Append Context Param1 with Parameters Param1
3. Set Context
```

But is it possible to do it from the frontend? We can access the context variable using `#contextA.variableB`. But can we write groovy or some other expression in the Argument section like `$variableB+#contextA.variableB` ?

I hope you got my ask, let me know if the question is not yet clear, I will try to give brief example as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Through the console alone, context parameters are set to the value of the parameters set from the sample phrases.

If you need to set context parameters to something else, you need to use fulfillment. You can use the built-in fulfillment editor, but you'll need to use something.

Comment: okay thanks. Yes, Google Dialgflow team should come up with something :P

Comment: yes, even that created dialogflow firebase/cloud function in the backend. so ideally both are same.